# Error while publish MVC3 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

Error   1   Copying file Content\themes\base\AdminHomeImages\GiftControl.jpg to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Content\themes\base\AdminHomeImages\GiftControl.jpg failed. Could not find file 'Content\themes\base\AdminHomeImages\GiftControl.jpg'.     0   0   ResturantManager

I get the above error while publishing MVC3 project.. What should i do to solve it.

Comment: Check whether the Content\themes\base\AdminHomeImages\GiftControl.jpg file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you choose to **Publish the Project** and Let's say your **Publish Method** is "**File System**" that means you are copying your necessary files from one location to another location. The Index of these files are mentioned in your project file. **You have two options below**

   (a) **Remove the Index** of these files(Files causing Compilation Error) from your Project File and Publish

   (b) It is must to keep the Project related Files to their exact location(Files that causing Compilation Error, Try keeping a fake file with same name and same Extension). This **relative path** is mentioned in your project file. Publish now
2. This **Compilation Error** will not be shown when you **Rebuild/Build** the application.

Comment: GiftControl.jpg was unknowingly moved to toher folder in the project. Putting it to correct folders solved the issue.